# How to interpret memory as big endian int16_t in x64 assembly?

Tags: assembly, optimization, bit-manipulation, x86-64

I'd like to better understand how an Intel CPU might efficiently pull big endian `int16_t`'s from memory. My assembly's not the greatest so I'm looking at the assembly results from clang.

One way to accomplish this in C would be:

```
int16_t n = bytes[i+2] | (int16_t)bytes[i+1] << 8;
```

Clang (with no flags) converts this line to:

```
movl -36(%rbp), %edx
addl $2, %edx
movslq %edx, %rax
movzbl -32(%rbp,%rax), %edx
movl -36(%rbp), %esi
addl $1, %esi
movslq %esi, %rax
movzbl -32(%rbp,%rax), %esi
movw %si, %di
movswl %di, %esi
shll $8, %esi
orl %esi, %edx
movw %dx, %di
movw %di, -46(%rbp)
```

I know there's a lot going on in the C code but this seems kinda crazy since it seems like just a matter of masks and moves.

Furthermore it seems like there must be something that could help out in the 981 x64 instructions (or whatever number you like to use).

Is there a more succinct way to do read memory as a big endian int16_t?

Comment: You forgot to enable optimization. PS: `+1` and `+2` sounds wrong, you normally use `+0` and `+1`. PS #2: if you have it, you can use `ntohs` function. Both `clang` and `gcc` generate a rotate for the conversion.

Comment: Welp, I'm a dummy. I had assumption that optimization would only do stuff like unroll loops. Man, I'm showing my age. This is what -03 gives:   movslq %ebx, %rax
  addl $2, %ebx
  movzwl .Lmain.bytes+1(%rax), %eax
  rolw $8, %ax

Comment: The final rotate is the actual conversion the rest is just the indexing and fetching.

Comment: Use `rol $8, %ax`, or (on newer CPUs only) `movbe (%rsi), %ax`.  Or work 16 bytes at a time with SSSE3 `pshufb` to byte-swap pairs of bytes in an xmm register.  (`bswap` is only available for 32 or 64-bit registers, and `rol` is efficient.  Far more efficient than `xchg %ah, %al`, BTW)

Comment: But compilers mostly do a good job with `ntohs` https://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohs or the [`<endian.h>` functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/endian.3.html) like `be16toh(uint16_t)`.  If you're using C, don't use inline asm for this.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm.  Related: a portable_endian.h that uses appropriate intrinsics across many different compilers: https://gist.github.com/PkmX/63dd23f28ba885be53a5